# Code coverage of Polymer Application with WCT

Tags: code-coverage, wct

I have the sapplication developed in Polymer and unit testing with WCT. I want to generate the code coverage report for that.

I tried with the istanbul`(web-component-tester-istanbul)`, but it is not supporting it, I am using Polymer Version `1.2`.

And I tried with Karma + Grunt, but I am not able to genrate the code coverage report.

Can anybody tell me how we can generate code coverage with Karma? I search on google but not able to find WCT with Karma.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the modified version for now till the original Istanbul is fixed to work with Polymer. [wct-Istanbub](https://github.com/Bubbit/wct-istanbub)